# How to measure graphics performance while drawing in JS?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a relatively simple website (small browser game) that does not perform well. Its graphic part is flickering and I'd like to measure how long it takes to draw different elements.

I draw in the method triggered by

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.drawAll());
```

To measure time, I've added to my drawing functions elements that capture the current time:

```
let t0 = new Date().getTime();
...
let t1 = new Date().getTime();
...
let t2 = new Date().getTime();
```

The intent was to display the delta between those numbers in the console, but the problem is that if you do it in the real-time console just freezes.

The idea I have is to accumulate time information and display it once a second (or for every 100 refresh cycles), but I'm wondering if there is any better way to do so?

Thanks!

EDIT: Idea to accumulate information did not work well: each part I'm concerned about is rendered decently fast and new Date().getTime() only counts milliseconds. The alternative is to use 'performance.now()' - it counts fractions of ms.

Comment: Instead of handwriting a bunch of code that measures times at specific points, [profile your program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97q8e.png) to determine the bottlenecks that need optimizing.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about that.

Comment: That's an interesting tool, but it does not help in my case. I don't have obviously long functions... I guess I'll post another question to handle that.

Comment: You could just [edit] your question since nobody's answered it yet

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear what you suggest me to edit, Patrick?

Comment: Unless you need a log of all values, just display your measurement in the page itself and overwrite the previous value - a basic average FPS count.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, Bergi! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate leaving questions without the answer.

Due to lack of better responses, I'll convert 'EDIT' part of the question to an answer:

I did end up with a few improvements to the idea:

1. Use 'performance.now()' instead of 'new Date().getTime()' to capture time
2. Don't output time snippets to console on every render event, but instead accumulate the duration of events in static variables as well as count the number of render events. When the counter reaches 100 (or any number that can help reasonably indicate performance difference) output accumulated data to console.

something like this:

```
static performanceEventCounter=0;
static duration1=0;
static duration2=0;

render() {
    let t0=performance.now();
    ...
    let t1=performance.now();
    ...
    let t2=performance.now();
    duration1+=t1-t0;
    duration2+=t2-t1;
    if(++performanceEventCounter>100) {
        console.log('duration1=${duration1}, duration2=${duration2}');
        performanceEventCounter=0;
        duration1=0;
        duration2=0;
    }
```